# Create subsite using custom site template programatically

Tags: feature, event-handlers, site-template, list, 2007

I Have a requirement where when a list item is created , a new subsite sould get Created using custom site template.(MOSS 2007)
User should be able to select the custom template(present in site gallery)from the dropdown field in the list. How do i do this?

Comment: Try to be more specific - what's the main problem? Triggering an action when a new list item is created? Deploying new site programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Each time I have approached this I have created a simple, intuitive form, with the required fields along with a sub-site of templates that you want to expose to the users.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally add a list event handler that will handle the item added event. When a new item is added, write the code required to create a new site based on the selected site template.

You will need to determine where the site should be created and the groups that should have access to the new site. Also, make sure you handle the possibility of a site already existing at the URL that you are using for the new site.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a site template. Beware of glitches in any lookup lists.